# Ember.js: setting an property whose value is a nested object

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Consider the following Ember object:

```
const FilterState = Ember.Object.extend({
  values: null,

  departmentChanged: Ember.observer('values.department_id', function() {
    // do something when the department changes
  }),
});

const filterState = FilterState.create({
  values: { department_id: 5, manager_id: 3 },
});
```

Then at some point in the app, we want to set the `filterState` values to a new set of values. Consider the following three alternatives to achieve this:

```
const newFilterValues = { department_id: 5 };

// This will unset the manager_id value, which is the desired behavior.
// However, it will trigger the departmentChanged observer,
// even though the department_id didn't actually change
filterState.set('values', newFilterValues);

// The following alternative won't trigger the observer, like intended
// but it won't unset the manager_id, which is necessary to happen
const filterValues = filterState.get('values');
Object.keys(newFilterValues).forEach(function(key) {
  filterValues.set(key, newFilterValues[key]);
});

// UPDATE:
// The following alternative is equivalent to the one just above,
// and therefore has the same shortcomings
filterState.
  get('values').
  setProperties(newFilterValues);
```

As the comments highlight, the first alternative gets the job done, but it "incorrectly" triggers the observer, even though the `values.department_id` property didn't really change.

The second and third alternatives don't trigger the observer, but both have a bigger flaw: the properties that **are not present** in the new set of filter values are not unset from the `filterState.values` object.

Currently the first one is the only option I can use, because the flaw on the second alternative is unacceptable. However, it would be desirable to not have the observer fire if it isn't really necessary.

My alternatives are:

1. I could try to cache the previous values and manually check inside the observer if the value really changed, but this seems too verbose and lame (this is what I'm currently doing).
2. Isn't there a way for Ember observer mechanism to pass the old values in the observer callback?
3. Or better yet, it there a way to achieve observers that will only fire if the properties really changed? (perhaps with some mixin magic?)
4. Or finally, is there some other way to set the new values from the `newFilterValues` object, in which the observer is not fired, but so that it also sets/unsets everything in the way it is intended?

Answer (score 0):

Define `values` as Ember.Object:

```
filterState: FilterState.create({
  values: Ember.Object.create({ 
    department_id: 5, manager_id: 3
  })
})
```

then it works, for example:

```
actions: {
  // will run observer only if department_id is changed
  changeDepartment: function(value) {
    var filterStateValues = this.get('filterState.values');
    filterStateValues.set('department_id', value);
  },
  // will not run observer
  changeOthers: function() {
    var filterStateValues = this.get('filterState.values');
    filterStateValues.setProperties({
      manager_id: 12
    });
  }
}
```

See jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/widivemewe/edit?js,output

Comment: Could work. But the intention is not to change one property at a time. It is to change the whole `filterState.values` object with a new object. This new object might not actually change all the properties in it. And in the example I just put two properties, but in my actual use case, these `values` object will have about a dozen properties or more.

Comment: 1) I think this is essential if `values` object is replaced then all properties `values.*` becomes changed.

2) You could use setProperties() to update multiple properties at once.

Comment: `setProperties(newValues)` will also have the shortcoming of not unsetting the properties not present in `newValues` but present in `filterState.values`. It's actually equivalent to the second of the alternatives I showed in the questions code snippets.